# Android: Custom Views not giving accessibility events in a ListView

Tags: android, view, android-listview, accessibility, talkback

I have a ListView that has an adapter with custom views in it. 
The custom view extends from RelativeLayout.

This view reports accessibility events from the text correctly if it is inside another View. If I add it to a ListView or a ViewPager, all of the custom views no longer provide accessibility events when TalkBack is enabled.

Why don't my custom views work correctly inside a ListView?

Comment: can you post relevant code and error log ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that if you assign a click listener to your View that's in a `ListView` or a `ViewPager`, you stop the accessibility events from propagating to those children.

Long story short, use `setOnItemSelectedListener` instead of `setOnClickListener`.